# store the state of HTML5 canvas with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, store, restore

I'm trying to edit [union draw](http://anonym.to/?http://www.unionplatform.com/?page_id=2762)

I want to store the state of the canvas,
so if a new visitor comes in, he will see the state of the last drawn stuff.
currently the canvas clears everything for the new visitor.

what do I have to do with union draw to store the state of the canvas?

Is it possible with something like this? If yes, how?

```
var states = [];
function saveState(ctx){
  var c = document.createElement('canvas');
  c.width  = ctx.canvas.width;
  c.height = ctx.canvas.height;
  c.getContext('2d').drawImage(ctx.canvas,0,0);
  states.push(c);
  return c;
}

function restoreState(ctx,idx){
  var off = idx==null ? states.pop() : states[idx];
  ctx.drawImage(off,0,0);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242006/html5-copy-a-canvas-to-image-and-back

Comment: Any mileage in storing pen moves and recreating when new visitor enters?

Comment: @Miszy 
no I don't mean saving the canvas as an image to harddrive

Comment: @jing3142
recreating the pen moves would be interesting too, but what I mean is the new visitor should see what has been drawn already on the canvas.

Comment: Have you looked at [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com)? It provides an API on top of the canvas and it allows you to import and export JSON or SVG. I'm not familiar with union draw so I don't know if it is compatible.